# Perfect matching in a tree

Tags: algorithm, tree, graph, binary-tree

I came across a definition of Perfect matching: a set of edges that touches each node exactly once.

However, i didnt really understand the definition. Can somebody give me an example of any such edge. Or may be point me towards some reference that does.

I tried to google but it didnt give me any example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A perfect matching set is any set of edges in a graph where every vertex in the graph is touched by exactly one edge in the matching set.  If you consider a graph with 4 vertices connected so that the graph resembles a square, there are two perfect matching sets, which are the pairs of parallel edges.  Since all the vertices are touched exactly once by either pair.  If you think about a graph with 3 vertices connected like a triangle, there is no perfect matching set, because if you take any pair of edges, one vertex is touched twice, but a single edge will always miss a vertex.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_matching

Your question mentions a tree, but a tree is just a special type of graph, so it still works the same.

Comment: Perhaps also mention that trees are bipartite graphs which have faster algorithms for finding matchings than those for general graphs.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, any graph with odd number of vertices cannot have a perfect matching edge set.

N edges => 2 * N vertices. Since no vertex once touched should not be touched again.